# How obtain variable value in HTML sendEmail body of javascript

Tags: html, google-apps-script

what syntax to get variable "skola" value in HTML body in
 span."  see attached image

```
  {  +<p>HERE MUST BE VARIABLE "skola"  VALUE<span style="color:
     red;"> + **skola** + </span> NOT IT NAME</p>|"}
```

[Here code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAHMD.jpg)

Comment: Instead of adding a screenshot of code, add the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the quote as you did in your previous lines. It must be

```
+'<p>blabla<span style="color: red;"> '+ skola + '</span> blabla</p>'
```

If you use double quote you must escape the double quote you use for the style param. It become :

```
+"<p>blabla<span style=\"color: red;\"> "+ skola + "</span> blabla</p>"
```

Stéphane

Comment: pleasure. Do ot hesitate to set it as good answer for others in the futur.